# variables in Selenium test

Tags: php, html, testing, selenium, selenium-ide

```
<tr>
   <td>type</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text + <?php echo $var ?></td>
</tr>
```

is possible add any variables for test in Selenium IDE? for example timestamp ?

Comment: did you try? and I don't think it does. as whatever the code you put under value is become string in converted format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This timestamp example works well:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{var date = new Date(); date.getTime();}</td>
    <td>var</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=.login</td>
    <td>${var}</td>
</tr>
```